# Why isn't Mike Zacharius in sos squad?

Tags: attack-on-titan

It was been clear that Mike is only second to live. If so, why isn't he in so squad? He took out 9 titans by himself we have seen from past episodes that even two people struggle with one titan. We haven't seen anything about the other SOS members during the Female Titan arc besides their excellent teamwork but if Mike is second to only Levi, he should be in SOS. Sos stands for Special Operation Squad.

Comment: The Squad members are handpicked by Levi. How Levi chose the squad was not explicitly stated. Besides, Mike is a squad leader like Levi. He probably considered that if Squad Mike were to be without a leader or with a new leader, they would have a hard time adjusting. Camaraderie and team work is just as important as strength, IMO. Or at least, that's how I see it.

Comment: You should that as an answer. Thank your for commenting.  @W.Are

Comment: Can't do that as it's just mostly my opinion. Quite hard to substantiate it with proof since it's just my interpretation of Levi's character. Thanks, too, though.